# Is it always important to cast explicitly?

Tags: vb.net

For example please see the code below:

```
Public sub routine1(byval strParam as string)

End sub

Public sub routine2()

    Dim intTest As Integer
    intTest = 1
    routine1(intTest)

End sub
```

Is it bad practice to rely on an implicit cast like in the above or is it important to always use an explicit cast. An explicit cast in the code above seems to be a waste to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving `Option Strict` on is generally considered good practice in VB.NET, because it can catch a lot of mistakes (and most people have it on anyways, so you may as well for compatibility). This code won’t work under `Option Strict`, so you should use `ToString()`, yes.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for reference to option strict. I know an integer is 32 bits and a long is 64. Therefore if you implicitly cast from a long to an integer then there is data loss. How does it work with strings? I believe that strings are the widest data type in .net.

Comment: @w0051977: `List`s are just as “wide”, and as for how it works with strings – it doesn’t. Not everything necessarily has a perfectly accurate string representation that is also the one you want to use, and `Option Strict` disables implicit narrowing conversions.

Comment: Getting into the habit of using ToString helps big time when you make your own class and have to write its properties to a file.  Overriding the ToString method wraps everything up nice and neat.